# Django won't migrate because one model used to be a subclass

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using Django 3.0.4 with MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have a model `Apples`.  I created a second model `BadApples` as a subclass of it:

```
# models.py

class Apples(models.Model):
    # fields
    
class BadApples(Apples):
    pass
```

I ran the migration, which completed successfully.

Then, I decided that the 'subclass' approach wasn't working and that `BadApples` should be its own model.  I rewrote the models like this:

```
# models.py

class Apples(models.Model):
    # fields
    
class BadApples(models.Model):
    # fields
```

When I tried to run the migration, I ran into the following error:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1090, "You can't delete all columns with ALTER TABLE; use DROP TABLE instead")
```

As best I can tell, migrating `BadApples` from one form to the other involves changing all of its columns.  Instead of dropping the table and recreating it, Django uses ALTER TABLE commands only, which throws the MySQL error when it attempts to remove the last column of the original `BadApples`.  This seems related to [this bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24424), purportedly fixed over two years ago, but evidently not fully.

To work around this bug, my idea was to remove `BadApples` from `models.py` and all references to `BadApples` from the rest of the code (in this case, `views.py` and `admin.py`).  Then I'd run a migration, which would drop the `BadApples` table entirely because it no longer exists, and then I could recreate it as a separate migration.

Instead, after confirming that there is no trace of the `BadApples` model anywhere in my code, running `makemigrations` throws this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'id' in class 'BadApples' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'Apples'.
```

When I originally created `BadApples` as a child of `Apples`, its table had no `id` field because its data was stored in the `Apples` table.  After I changed it to be an independent model, its table now gets assigned an `id` field.  Django retains some memory of `BadApples` being a child of `Apples`, however, and it sees this as a conflict.

To try to fix this, I reverted to the migration immediately before I ever created `BadApples` in the first place.  This migration completed successfully:

```
$ python3 manage.py migrate AppName 0012_auto_some_number
Operations to perform:
  Target specific migration: 0012_auto_some_number, from AppName
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Unapplying AppName.0013_badapples... OK
```

At this point, there is NO reference to `BadApples` anywhere in my code, and the models are at a point where `BadApples` has never even existed.  Yet, when I try to run a migration (with no further changes to `models.py`), I still get the error

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'id' in class 'BadApples' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'Apples'.
```

Django is fixated on the idea that `BadApples` used to exist and be a subclass of `Apples`.  How do I un-fixate it?

Answer (score 1):

This type of operation you're trying to perform is sufficiently complicated that Django Migrate can't infer what you're trying to do. In situations like these you should write a [custom migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/writing-migrations/) to handle how it can migrate the database forward. In this migration you can tell it to properly drop the table and create a new one.

In the [Migration Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#migration-files) topic there is an example that shows the [`migrations.DeleteModel()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/migration-operations/#deletemodel) method.

```
from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [('migrations', '0001_initial')]

    operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel('Tribble'),
        migrations.AddField('Author', 'rating', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
    ]
```

Comment: This is good information, and thanks, but what Django can and can't handle as a migration is the type of thing it needs to tell me *before* I spring an unresolvable error, either through documentation or through a warning message.  As it stands, I can't apply this solution because I can't run any migration commands without getting the error noted in my post.