# Why does Django complain that a new model column is unknown instead of migrating it?

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 3.0 with Python 3.6.  I have a Model:

```
class Data(models.Model):

    parameter = models.CharField(
        max_length=16,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    mode = models.CharField(
        max_length=8,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

Everything was working fine.  Then, I added one field to the Model:

```
class Data(models.Model):

    parameter = models.CharField(
        max_length=16,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    mode = models.CharField(
        max_length=8,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    code = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

Having done nothing else, I tried to run a migration.  It results in this error:

```
$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
...
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'appName_data.code' in 'field list'")
```

Which, yeah, no shit it's an unknown column, that's why I want you to add it to the table.

I've tried searching for this error, but all I can find is stuff on Stack Overflow from before 2008 that I can't make apply to my situation, and some old obscure bug reports that I can't even begin to read.

What do I do?

**Edit:**

I added the column manually:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE appName_data ADD code VARCHAR(64) NULL;
```

After this, `makemigrations` would run successfully, but when I try to execute the migration itself, I get the error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'code'")
```

At the time, `models.py` still had the `code` column defined.  I deleted that field and tried again, but the `migrate` step returns the same error either way.

No clue how to proceed.

Comment: How many other migrations have you made up to this point? You can use `manage,py showmigrations` to get a list.

Comment: Several.  I did previously have migration problems, but I had resolved them, at least at the time.  Unfortunately, `showmigrations` throws the same error as in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please share your migrations ?

Looks like your database went out synch for some reason ?
One quick and dirty way is to add the column to the database manually like this : ( Do not do it yet, let me see your migrations first! )

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

check tables and select the targeted table which in this case is appName_data

```
sqlite> .tables
```

and then add code column to the database

like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD new_column_name column_definition;
```

in your case:

```
sqlite>ALTER TABLE appName_data
      ...>ADD core VARCHAR(64) NULL ;
```

Comment: Running `showmigrations` results in the same error, so I'm not sure how to share them.  I wouldn't be surprised if the DB were out of sync; a little while back I hit an [unresolved bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65324136/django-wont-migrate-because-one-model-used-to-be-a-subclass) that I had to work around.  I'm prepared to add the column manually unless you think there's a danger that will mess things up too much.

Comment: No danger at all! Worst case scenario ! You will have to remove the column that is about it. Add the column , it should run fine

Comment: I tried adding the column manually, but it didn't get me far.  I've updated my question with the attempt and its results.

Comment: Hi , would you please share your migrations and the targeted table on the database? Go to your migrations  folder and show me the code there. You do not need to do comigrations.